# Why does nautilus use 90%+ cpu at startup?

Tags: nautilus, startup

When I log into my account, nautilus uses about 90~95% of CPU. What is it doing?

Comment: Please be a little more elaborate. Is it just after you login? If the utilization normalizes, it may be just that nautilus is initializing your desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nautilus uses a lot of CPU when you log in as part of the process of loading your desktop and setting up a few things behind the scenes. So long as it returns to a normal level a little later, nothing is wrong with your system, and there is little you could do to change that happening.